# Remove or blend background of video using CSS?

Tags: css, html5-video, mix-blend-mode, background-blend-mode

I am trying to make the solid background of a HTML5 video blend in with the background of the page.

I've tried using `mix-blend-mode` though the vide stays same. Is there a way to do this via CSS?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qsg4but/) (the video background should be gray like the container). I try two approaches (blend mode on the main container and blend mode on a separate, special container for the video.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="container">

  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/013/330/original/Thin_Smoke_80_-_4K_res.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

<div id="container-two">

  <div id="inner-container">



    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/013/330/original/Thin_Smoke_80_-_4K_res.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
   video{
     mix-blend-mode:multiply;
   }
    #container{
      background-color:gray;
      height:500px;
      width: 100%;
      mix-blend-mode:multiply;
    }
    #container-two{
      background-color:gray;
      height:500px;
      width: 100%;
      mix-blend-mode:multiply;
    }
    #inner-container{
      background-color:gray;
      height:500px;
      width: 100%;
      mix-blend-mode:multiply;
    }
```

Comment: Could you not make the background black as that seems to be the colour of the video you are using, or is it a different video that may be dynamic and change colour?

Comment: This is just a sample, but the actual project the background color is set in stone, and the video, when rendered, doesn't always match.

Comment: because video is rendered as a discrete object, you're probably going to have to transfer frame by frame to a canvas and apply your blend to that

Comment: Thanks. Is there a downside to using this method, such as load time, speed/performance?